# visual studio 2015 referencing an added project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a visual studio 2015 project; lets call it the main project. I have added another project to it. But my main project does not 'see' my added project. How do make the main project reference or 'see' the added project.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your main project

somewhere in the menu there is a references item.

click that, and it opens up a dialog which will let you pick the associated project as a dependency.

Then when you rebuild all, that dependency will be rebuilt before the main one.

Comment: I have followed the above instructions. So this is what I did: added the second project to my main project. Now when I try to add reference to the solution from the folder that has the second project; 1. I don't see the project solution. So I chose 'All Files' from the drop down menu. And then when I try to reference the xxxx.sln or xxxx.csproj file I get the following error: A reference to 'xxxx.sln' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component. I cannot build the whole project because the main project uses the second one.

Comment: I also want to mention that the second project references a NuGet Package.

Comment: The main and the second projects were a VS 2010 projects which were converted to VS 2015 projects successfully. The OS is 2012 r2 server.

Answer (score 0):

In your main project you can add a reference to the second project. In the Solution Explorer in the main project just right click on 'References', in the window select 'Projects' and pick the project you want to reference.

[image]